# NGXS: How to get the RouteHandler to work?

Tags: ngxs

When creating a ngxs RouteHandler according to the documentation found here:

https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/action-handlers

I get a NullInjectorError when I add:

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: noop,
      deps: [RouteHandler],
      multi: true
    }
  ]
```

Has anyone successfully dispatched routes from an ngxs action using this documented RouteHandler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one stumped me for a little bit.
What I found, at least in my case, is that the docs failed to mention you need to set { providedIn: 'root' } in the "service" - so to speak.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' });
```

Everything else was pretty much the same as explained in the docs.
I also (quickly) made a stackblitz which should give you a general idea as to how things should be set up.
https://stackblitz.com/github/baxelson12/ngxs-route-handlers